# kill sudo with specific time every time

Tags: password, sudo, kill

we all know that in Ubuntu sudo password will be [auto saved for 15 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277900/whats-the-default-sudo-timeout) and expires after that. But I want to make it for quick expire. I mean I dont want to change any settings and when I ever I want , My system should have to release the password with out storing for 15 min. I mean it should store only 3 min or 4 min for example.

how can i do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel the currently-applied remaining sudo time-out?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out)

Comment: @Takkat did you mean its not possible ?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking - and how it is not answered in the previous answers which you linked to in your question? Specifically by https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: @steeldriver I did that at OLi answer. please check it out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out

Comment: Close-voters: The question (as I read it) is about a setting to permanently shorten the timeout to 3 minutes, so not a duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out at least.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your sudoers file with `sudo visudo` and add the following line after the existing defaults:

```
Defaults    timestamp_timeout=3
```

Note: `visudo` doesn't *mean* it'll neccessarily edit it with vi/vim/etc but if you find your $EDITOR value is sqwiffed-up and you'd prefer nano, you can run `sudo EDITOR=nano visudo` instead to force nano to be your editor.

The trick from the [suggested duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out), (`sudo -k`) is good for an immediate privilege dump.

Comment: Boss I want to have temp expire , like "" sudo apt-get install <someappl> & Remember password only for 2 min and then expire ""

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that on a when-you-like basis. You can either apply the timestamp_timeout to everybody, specific users/commands inside, both in sudoers or manually with the sudo -k command.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the remaining sudo timetout with

```
sudo -k
```

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/14948/107450)

But if you want to change the default from 15 minutes you can do so by

```
sudo visudo
```

This opens an editor and points it to the sudoers file -- Ubuntu defaults to nano, other systems use Vi. You're now a super user editing one of the most important files on your system. No stress!

(Vi specific instructions noted with (vi!). Ignore these if you're using nano)

Use the arrow keys to move to the end of the Defaults line.

(vi!) press the A (capital "a") key to move at the end of the current line and enter editing mode (append after the last character on the line).

Now type

```
,timestamp_timeout=X
```

where X is the timeout expiration in minutes. If you specify 0 you will always be asked the password. If you specify a negative value, the timeout will never expire. E.g.

```
Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=5
```

(vi!) hit Escape to return to command mode. Now, if you're happy with your editing, type in :w  to write the file and :q  to exit vi. If you made a mistake, perhaps the easiest way is to redo from start, to exit without saving (hit Escape to enter the command mode) and then type :q! .

hit CTRL + X, then Y, then  to save your file and exit nano.

You might want to read the sudoers and vi manual pages for additional information.

```
man sudoers

man vi
```

<sub>Most of this lifted directly from [RootSudoTimeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout) in The [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found that , use `at` command.

i mean

```
sudo apt-get install <application> & echo "sudo -k" | at now + 2 min
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can concatenate the `sudo -k`

```
sudo apt-get install package ; sudo -k
```

The method could be anything that allows you to remove sudo permissions at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following bash function (I have not tested this well):

```
function tmpsudo {
    sudo ${*:2}
    (sleep $(($1 * 60)) && sudo -k) &
}
```

You would use it like so for a 2 minute timeout:

```
tmpsudo 2 command
```

It's really messy and there's no timer-reset, but it's an option.

Comment: Boss we can use at also right ? and Its very easy boss.